# Angular 7 Local Storage

Tags: angular, typescript

I have looked around the web and found the best way to use local Storage is to have it in a service I have a login controller that sends an API token and user details in its response I am setting those details in local Storage and then I am using angular router to navigate to my dashboard in the header I am getting the set local Storage but the DOM doesn't update I though if I subscribed to the local storage service it would update but ti doesn't work can someone point me in the right direction for what I need to do to get the header to update when the user logs in and should I use a different type of local Storage since there is others out there Thank you in advance

```js
/*header Component*/
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LocalStorageService } from '../../global-services/localstorage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  user: any;

    constructor(
              private Shared: SharedService,
              private router: Router,
              private local: LocalStorageService) { }
  fave: any;
    ngOnInit() {
      this.getLocal();
    }
    getLocal() {
        this.local.getLocal().subscribe(
          data => {
            this.user = data;
          }
        );


    }
    logout() {
      this.local.logout();
    }
}
/*LocalStorage Service*/
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocalStorageService {

    setLocal(user) {
      return localStorage.getItem(user);

    }
    getLocal() {
      return localStorage.getItem('user')
    }

    logout() {
    return localStorage.removeItem('user');
    }
}
/* Login Component*/
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LocalStorageService } from '../../global-services/localstorage.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private api: LoginService,
    private router: Router,
    private local: LocalStorageService) { }
/*Vars*/
  user: any;
  email: string;
  password: string;

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onSubmit() {
    this.api.login(this.email, this.password).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.user = data;
        localStorage.setItem('api_token', this.user.api_token),
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
      }
    );
    this.local.setLocal(this.user);
  }
}
```

```html
/*Header HTML*/
<nav class="uk-navbar-container uk-margin nav1" uk-navbar="mode: click" *ngIf="router.url != '/login'">
  <div class="uk-navbar-left">
    <ul class="uk-navbar-nav nav1">
      <li class="uk-active nav1"><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li class="nav1"><a href="/form">Create form</a></li>
      <li class="nav1"><a uk-icon="icon: books" href="/books"></a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
<div class="uk-position-right favBtn">
  <a *ngIf="this.user !== null" uk-icon="icon: user" class="uk-button uk-button-default"style="border:none;">{{user.message}}  {{user.last_name}}</a>
    <a uk-icon="icon: sign-in" *ngIf="this.user == null" href="/login" style="border:none; color:white;">Login</a>
    <div *ngIf="this.user !== null" uk-dropdown="mode: click" class=" uk-width-large" uk-dropdown>
      <hr class="uk-divider-icon uk-width-1-1">
      <div class="uk-child-width-1-1@s" uk-grid>
        <a uk-icon="icon: sign-out" href="/login" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LocalStorage doesn't provide any streams to you. Those are just static values. If you use that service correctly (your app share one its instance), probably would be enough just to return the value from localStorage:

```
getLocal() {
  this.user = this.local.getLocal();
```

p.s. also other methods doesnt make sense, ex.:

```
setLocal(user) {
      return localStorage.getItem(user);
```

1. not `getItem`, but `setItem`
2. No need to return it

Comment: Oh sorry about the wrong code and about  the returns I was trying to use a subscribe I thought that would work but I didnt realise its not a stream

Comment: Thank you I had to parse the data first it works now

Answer (score 0):

In your LoginService I would create a variable `isLoggedIn = false`.
Set this to true within your subscription before you navigate to dashboard.

```
...
this.api.isLoggedIn = true;
this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
```

Now in your HeaderComponent import your LoginService as well. So you have access to this variable.

Instead of `*ngIf="router.url != '/login'"` use `*ngIf="!api.isLoggedIn"`

Answer (score 0):

You should use EventEmitter to instantly reflect your login status. Here is the detail for how to use https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Example

```
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BaseService {
  @Output() isLoggedin: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  authenticate(data:any){
    this.http.post(path,data).subscribe( (res:any) => {
      console.log(res)
      if(res.status == "success")
      {
        this.isLoggedin.emit(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

When a variable emit value. the the subscriber will reflect with new value.